# Local system corresponding to induced representation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, terminology, notation

Let $p\colon Y\to X$ be a finite covering map of path-connected "good" spaces (e.g. manifolds), and let $L$ be a local system on $Y$, and let $V$ be the corresponding representation of $\pi_1(Y)$. Then $p_*L$ is the local system on $X$ corresponding to the representation $\operatorname{Ind}_{\pi_1(Y)}^{\pi_1(X)} V$. Is there any standard notation for this local system? I was thinking something like $\operatorname{Ind}_Y^X L$.

Comment: Why not $p_*L$?

Comment: @DanielLitt For the use I have in mind, I have a whole plethora of covering maps, and it'd be a pain to have to name each one.

Comment: Well, sorry, but that's the standard notation for it.

Comment: @BenWebster well, I guess that's my answer.